# jQuery -detecting if CSS animation ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

Just bootstrapping a quick modal script and I hit the wall.

Testing css animations and all works fine. I can open a modal from a link but when I try to open same modal again straight after for some reason

```
.one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd",
     function(e){
        modalBg.removeClass('flex fadeOut animated');
        $(this).off(e);

     });
```

is fired instantly... When I try to click different link every time it works fine. I did try to null `modalBg` variable and it does the trick but console return the error that `removeClass` is not defined. So for some reason `modalBg.removeClass('flex fadeOut animated');` is still fired.

Here is [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/rajezi/edit?html,css,js,output)

Here is the whole code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( ".modal-link" ).on( "click", function() {

        attribute = $(this).attr('href');
        attribute = attribute.replace('#','');
        console.log(attribute);

        $('.modal-bg[data-modal='+ attribute +']').addClass( "flex animated fadeIn" );
        $('.modal-bg[data-modal='+ attribute +'] .modal').addClass( "animated fadeInDown" );
});

$('.modal-close').on('click', function() {
    modalBg = $(this).closest('.modal-bg');
    modalBg.removeClass('fadeIn');
    modalBg.addClass('fadeOut');
    modalBg.one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd",
     function(e){
        modalBg.removeClass('flex fadeOut animated');
        $(this).off(e);

     });
   });
});
```

Comment: I feel like you need to use the jQuery animate function to take advantage of the on finish animate handler.

Comment: @Mistergreen, that's not an issue, it is working fine with keyframe css animations. I can't figure out why event is triggered when I click on the same link twice in the row... Interesting enough when I click link third time it's working again :) I don't want use jQuery animations they quite slow compering to css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your off(e) with

`$(this).off("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd");`